# Uncheck a radio button in case another one is checked in a ListView using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radio-button

I have a list of radio buttons that are generated dynamically by a ListView. Each radio button refers to the ID of a different image.

Now instead of checking the radio button I want the user to be able to click on the image instead and the radio button is checked automatically. So far so good. I've reached that stage.

However I want the user to check only one image, which means that if a new image is clicked the radio button of the previous ones must be unchecked. I tried many ways but none worked. Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
           $(".SmallSquarePhoto").click(function () {
           var RadioValue = $(this).attr("myAttribute"); //Get the value of myAttribute
           $('input[myAttribute=' + RadioValue + ']').attr('checked', 'checked'); //Check the radiobutton that corresponds to the image that was clicked
           $("#SmallSquarePhoto" + RadioValue).css("border-color", "#51cf25"); //Create a green border around the selected image
           $('[id^="SmallSquarePhoto"]:not(#SmallSquarePhoto' + RadioValue + ')').css("border-color", "white"); //Remove the green border from the previous image that was selected                    
           $("#<%=FormView3.FindControl("UpdateButton").ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled'); //Enable the Change button in case an image is clicked
// SO FAR SO GOOD
           //Here I want to uncheck the radio buttons that don't correspond to the latest clicked image. How?
           });
        });
    });


<itemtemplate>
<div id="SmallSquarePhoto<%# Eval("ID_BG") %>" class="SmallSquarePhoto" style="cursor:pointer; border-width: 4px; background-image: url(/Members/images/background/<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>)" myAttribute='<%# Eval("ID_BG") %>' >
<input id="Radio1" name="BG_list" type="radio" runat="server" myAttribute='<%# Eval("ID_BG") %>' value='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>' />
</div>
</itemtemplate>
```

And here is the HTML output

```
<div id="SmallSquarePhoto269" class="SmallSquarePhoto" style="background-image: url(150301-110930-1.jpg               )" myAttribute='269' >
<input value="150301-110930-1.jpg               " name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ListView1$ctrl0$BG_list" type="radio" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_Radio1_0" myAttribute="269" />
</div>

<div id="SmallSquarePhoto266" class="SmallSquarePhoto" style="background-image: url(150301-110104-1.jpg               )" myAttribute='266' >
<input value="150301-110104-1.jpg               " name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ListView1$ctrl1$BG_list" type="radio" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_Radio1_1"  myAttribute="266" />
</div>
```

UPDATE
The solution was the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            $(".SmallSquarePhoto").click(function () {
                var RadioValue = $(this).attr("myAttribute"); //Get the value of myAttribute
                $('[id^="SmallSquarePhoto"]:not(#SmallSquarePhoto' + RadioValue + ')').css("border-color", "white"); //Remove the green border from the previous image that was selected                    
                $("#<%=FormView3.FindControl("UpdateButton").ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled'); //Enable the Change button in case an image is clicked
                $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false); //NEW
                $('input[myAttribute=' + RadioValue + ']').prop('checked', 'checked'); //NEW
                $("#SmallSquarePhoto" + RadioValue).css("border-color", "#51cf25"); //Create a green border around the selected image
           });
    });
   });
```

Comment: Note: For jQuery questions, a copy of the output page HTML (e.g. saved from the browser) is preferable to the ASP.Net source code. Makes mocking up example far easier :)

Comment: I also note you have `runat="server"` on your template control. Was that intentional?

Comment: Yes. without runat="server" I can't get values needed to run the jQuery script

Comment: Can you please show the output HTML? That will make a mockup easy. Mentally compiling ASP.Net is no fun :)

Comment: It works now based on @Akash Chavda solution

Comment: "works" is a loose term. :) There appear to be multiple issues with the code, but the example shown is incomplete. If you were to post the HTML as advised you would get much better results.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  Plz see the html output in my question

Comment: Because you are using a `runat=` server, your `name=` attributes are *not* the same. Please post the *entire* source and the *entire* page HTML :)

Comment: You may also want to use `varchar` fields in your database (not `char`) for the image filenames (or at least trim them). You have huge amounts of whitespace injected.

Comment: Thanks.... I've noticed that so I've change the db field to NVARCHAR

Comment: `n`varchar is only required for unicode characters. Most filenames will be fine with varchar :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75129/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-gloria).

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
               $(".SmallSquarePhoto").click(function () {
               var RadioValue = $(this).attr("myAttribute"); //Get the value of myAttribute
               $('[id^="SmallSquarePhoto"]:not(#SmallSquarePhoto' + RadioValue + ')').css("border-color", "white"); //Remove the green border from the previous image that was selected                    
               $("#<%=FormView3.FindControl("UpdateButton").ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled'); //Enable the Change button in case an image is clicked
               $('[id^="SmallSquarePhoto"]').prop('checked', false);
               $('input[myAttribute=' + RadioValue + ']').prop('checked', 'checked'); //Check the radiobutton that corresponds to the image that was clicked
               $("#SmallSquarePhoto" + RadioValue).css("border-color", "#51cf25"); //Create a green border around the selected image
               });
            });
        });


    <itemtemplate>
    <div id="SmallSquarePhoto<%# Eval("ID_BG") %>" class="SmallSquarePhoto" style="cursor:pointer; border-width: 4px; background-image: url(/Members/images/background/<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>)" myAttribute='<%# Eval("ID_BG") %>' >
    <input id="Radio1" name="BG_list" type="radio" runat="server" myAttribute='<%# Eval("ID_BG") %>' value='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>' />
    </div>
    </itemtemplate>
```

I'm not sure but i think it's helpful to you.